# An element of SL(2, $\mathbb{Z}$) as a homothety

Tags: elliptic-curves, integer-lattices

Per example 1.33 on page 13 in [this document](https://www.hse.ru/data/2014/11/13/1101420183/2013.04.03.pdf), how does an element of SL(2,$\mathbb{Z}$) act on the plane in a way that could be a homothety? Is it via matrix multiplication or as a linear fractional transformation?

Comment: What makes you think it "could be a homothety"?

Comment: the wording in the section "The stabilizer of a lattice $L$ in $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ is the
group of basis changes of $L$ that amount to homotheties of $\mathbb{C}$.